# Easypost Node.js Example Difficulties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, easypost

I'm currently trying to implement the Easypost API however the example from the docs is console logging null on my front-end (localhost:3000)... does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks... First time using using firebase as well as easypost & react

functions/index.js:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const EasyPost = require("@easypost/api");

const api = new EasyPost(TEST_API_KEYS);

exports.buyShipping = functions.https.onCall((data, res) => {
  const shipment = new api.Shipment({
    from_address: {
      street1: "417 MONTGOMERY ST",
      street2: "FLOOR 5",
      city: "SAN FRANCISCO",
      state: "CA",
      zip: "94104",
      country: "US",
      company: "EasyPost",
      phone: "415-123-4567",
    },
    to_address: {
      name: "Dr. Steve Brule",
      street1: "179 N Harbor Dr",
      city: "Redondo Beach",
      state: "CA",
      zip: "90277",
      country: "US",
      phone: "4155559999",
    },
    parcel: {
      length: 8,
      width: 5,
      height: 5,
      weight: 5,
    },
  });

  shipment.save().then((s) => {
    s.buy(shipment.lowestRate()).then((result) => {
      return result;
    });
  });

  });
});
```

frontend:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions';

///

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const functions = getFunctions(app);
const buyShipping = httpsCallable(functions, 'buyShipping')

const buy = async () => {              
       await buyShipping().then((result) => {
          /** @type {any} */
          console.log(result)
    })} 

///

<button onClick={buy}>Purchase</button>
```

Comment: I checked the logs from firebase functions I received a tracking link, a rate and a carrier_account_id... does that mean it's working properly?

Comment: The firebase logs also look like it keeps making multiple labels repeatedly... I think that's why I saw a ```Maximum call stack size exceeded``` error there maybe?

Comment: It's best to add comments like the above to the question. Helps clarify what's being asked.

Comment: @Jay Okay I changed the code and now those two things I mentioned aren't happening anymore... I also updated the code, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem; I can't have a return within the shipment.save function in my firebase backend... this worked:

```
exports.buyShipping = functions.https.onCall((data, res) => {
  const shipment = new api.Shipment({
    from_address: {
      street1: "417 MONTGOMERY ST",
      street2: "FLOOR 5",
      city: "SAN FRANCISCO",
      state: "CA",
      zip: "94104",
      country: "US",
      company: "EasyPost",
      phone: "415-123-4567",
    },
    to_address: {
      name: "Dr. Steve Brule",
      street1: "179 N Harbor Dr",
      city: "Redondo Beach",
      state: "CA",
      zip: "90277",
      country: "US",
      phone: "4155559999",
    },
    parcel: {
      length: 8,
      width: 5,
      height: 5,
      weight: 5,
    },
  });

  const arrayData = shipment.save().then((s) => {
    return s;
  });
  return arrayData;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are console logging on your backend which won't do anything useful. You'll instead want to return the result of your `buyShipping` call from the backend so that your frontend can then display it on the page or console log it or whatever you are intending to do with it. Additionally, your two function calls don't share the same name so you aren't actually calling your backend most likely (based on the example provided). `buyShipping` is the name of the function on the backend but you are calling `sendPackage` on the frontend.

You'll want all your logic living on your backend Node server and do nothing with it there except return. Then all your "representation" logic (displaying, logging, etc) will happen on the frontend by calling those functions from the backend.

Comment: I changed the cloud function and front end after reading this and now the firebase log just says ```Finished with status: response error```

Comment: New cloud function code: ```shipment.save().then((s) => {
    s.buy(shipment.lowestRate()).then((result) => {
      return result;
    });
  });```

Comment: New front end code (changed from sendPackage to buyShipping): ```const buy = async () => {              
       await buyShipping().then((result) => {
          /** @type {any} */
          console.log(result)
    })}```

Comment: I updated the new functions in the original question above to give a better visual